# What data should I use for this query to return results?

Tags: sql, mysql

This is my SQL query. I have data in my tables for this query. But this query doesn't return any results.

```
Select Prod_Batch_ID,tbl_product.product_name, Quantity,DATE_FORMAT(Production_Date, '%W, %D %M %Y') from tbl_production,tbl_product where tbl_production.Product_ID  = tbl_product.Product_ID and (Production_Date between STR_TO_DATE('2010-01-01 00:00:00.000','%m/%d/%Y')and DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2010-12-12 00:00:00.000','%m/%d/%Y'), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

The Production_Date column in the table is of timestamp type. Is converting to date using str_to_date the problem here?

Comment: are you sure it should be returning data?

Comment: @codethis yes. i am sure it should be returning data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your STR_TO_DATE format strings are wrong. Try

```
%Y-%m-%d
```

Or

```
%Y-%m-%d %h-%i-%s
```

You need to match the date format to the string you are passing in.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can't query against timestamp columns.  To quote from SQL Server Books Online:

> The SQL Server timestamp data type has
>   nothing to do with times or dates. SQL
>   Server timestamps are binary numbers
>   that indicate the relative sequence in
>   which data modifications took place in
>   a database. The timestamp data type
>   was originally implemented to support
>   the SQL Server recovery algorithms.

Comment: so do you say that i should convert the column to date datatype...?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server and intend to use it like a date/time then yes change it from timestamp.  Timestamp is intended for other purposes and very difficult to work with.  If you are using mySQL timestamp isn't so bad but still better to use datetime if you have that option.

Comment: I was curious if datetime was as useless in mySQL as it is in SQL Server, so created a quick table in mySQL. mySQL isn't so bad I was able to query against timestamp via: between '2010-12-01' and '2010-12-05'